# Toggle Switch State Based on JSON data

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-bootstrap-toggle

I am still a noobie to angular dev, I had a couple of proposed solutions to my problem, but didn't realize how to implement them. 
I am using [Angular Bootstrap Toggle] Switch in my angular expression to control on/off values for multiple parameters.

The state of the toggle (ON/OFF) is based on ng-model="toggleValue", where it expects the toggle value to be the boolean type, i.e. true, false.

Now the data that I import from my database(oracledb) has this parameter "toggleValue" defined as "Y"(True) or "N"(False). How do I make the toggle switch complaint to support the Y/N values?

Solutions thought of:
1) Convert the incoming JSON values from Y to true and N to false.
2) bind ng-model to expressions which evaluate to true if the value is 'Y' else false.
3) Hack Angular Bootstrap toggle JS script. (least preferred)

[View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy3qe.png)

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/3gt64xz8/1/

```
<toggle ng-model="item.SHIP_FROM_STORE_IND" aria-label="SFS Switch" size="btn-xs"></toggle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a couple of solutions may work for this problem. Again I don't necessarily feel these are the most optimum solutions, as regardless we will have to iterate our data object and convert the values of required key: value pair from 'Y' to true and 'N' to false.

**1) ng-init**

I created a parent division over the division where I was required to use these ng-model variables, and reassigned the values of toggleValue with the following code, as ng-init permits using expressions, which ng-model doesn't

```
<div ng-init="item.SHIP_FROM_STORE_IND = init(item.SHIP_FROM_STORE_IND);
 item.BOPIS_ENABLED_IND=init(item.BOPIS_ENABLED_IND); 
 item.BOSTS_ENABLED_IND=init(item.BOSTS_ENABLED_IND)">
```

Init function in controller:

```
$scope.init = function(value) {
$scope.testInput= (value=='Y')? true:false;
return $scope.testInput;
}
```

Pros: Since I am using ng-repeat and pagination, only the scope elements of the current page are changed, and thus more efficient, and iteratively others are changed on page change. 
cons: I also have a search box in my view, which lets you filter the records based on toggleValue parameter (true/false). Now if the filter is applied, it only filters out the current page elements and not all the elements as they are still in "Y" or "N" values.

**2) Iterate the object and swap the value in controller while fetching the data**

This is pretty simple and obvious solution, but obviously not the most efficient one.

```
$scope.items = storeFactory.getRecords().query(
    function(response) {
        $scope.items=response;
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.items.length;
        for (var i=0, len=$scope.totalItems; i<len; i++) {
            $scope.items[i].toggleValue = ($scope.items[i].SHIP_FROM_STORE_IND=='Y')? true:false;
        }

    },
    function(response) {
        $scope.waitMessage = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
    });
```

Similarly, we can convert the data back during any changes/updates made back to server.

Comment: I believe this solution solve the problem but is a hack. I am temporarily accepting this as an answer and will change if we some other proposed solution.